# How to compare two date in a maven application java

Tags: java, spring, date, hql, where-clause

I create a function to fetch some rows that matches the Date. But the function is not performing accordingly. I suspect there is some syntax issue. Please help me finding the issue.
The DaoImpl funtion is given below:

```
public List<ReportSewing> getReport(Date reportDate) {
     return session.getCurrentSession()
             .createQuery("from ReportSewing where DATE(reportDate) = (reportDate)")
             .list();
}
```

Comment: And how do you expect a `reportDate` which is a `String` to be converted to a `Date`? You are ignoring the passed in `reportDate`. You should have something like this as the query `"FROM ReportSewing where reportDate=:reportDate"` and then add `setParameter("reportDate", reportDate)` before the `list()` to make it work.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In case i want to check two conditions in where how i should modify the code? 
  m-deinum

Comment: extend your where clause and add an additional `setParameter`. I strongly suggest a read on how JPA works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to pass query parameter.

```
public List<ReportSewing> getReport(Date reportDate) {
     return session.getCurrentSession()
         .createQuery("from ReportSewing where DATE(reportDate) = :reportDate")
         .setParameter("reportDate", reportDate)
         .list();
}
```

Comment: In case i want to check two conditions in where how i should modify the code?

Comment: @Sabuj what condition? reportDate check ?

Comment: @mabin Joe See below how can i set parameter for lineNo?
public List<ReportSewing> getReport(Date reportDate) {
     return session.getCurrentSession()
         .createQuery("from ReportSewing where DATE(reportDate) = :reportDate" and lineNo=:lineno)
         .setParameter("reportDate", reportDate);
         .list();
}

Comment: @Sabuj Just add setParameter("lineno", lineno). `return session.getCurrentSession()
         .createQuery("from ReportSewing where DATE(reportDate) = :reportDate")
         .setParameter("reportDate", reportDate).setParameter("lineno", lineno)
         .list();`